# How to empty GDM log files?

Tags: gnome, gdm, bug-reporting, log, ubuntu-bug

I want to create a bugreport using `ubuntu-bug` and I would like to include the log files of *Gnome Display Manager (GDM)* which I found in `/var/log/gdm`. To minimize the noise that may be in the logs I would like to **empty** them before I reproduce the bug.

What is the best way to empty the log files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several ways to do this. You can move the log file to a backup with

```
sudo mv gdm.log gdm.log.old
```

and then you can create an empty file with

```
sudo touch gdm.log
```

Comment: Do you know if it is safe to delete them? If so, which files - all in the directory?

Comment: The files ending on `.[0-9]` are older logs (zipped files). Any log you delete here should be recreated when needed by the system so it should be safe. Always better to create a backup though ;)